# Tornado vs sound speed

Tags: forces, acoustics, atmospheric-science, vortex, weather

A tornado can be faster than sound, on Earth? Please explain as for a 6 years old (I am not the one interested in tornadoes).

Comment: Where did you hear this? As far as I know, it's incorrect.

Comment: Possibly on another planet though: https://revisionworld.com/a2-level-level-revision/physics/force-motion/momentum-second-law/momentum-second-law-0

Comment: A tornado is slower but more devastating than subsonic sound.

Comment: Explain as for a 6 years old?  [Impossible](https://xkcd.com/1364/).

Answer (score 2):

No, a tornado does not move faster than the speed of sound in any way. A quick google search claims that the most extreme tornados can attain speeds over 500 km/h. For reference, that's about 140 m/s. The speed of sound is almost three times that at about 345 m/s.

Answer (score 1):

A tornado or any wind cannot probably attain sound speed on Earth, as others have written. Else we should know of that. However, considering that wind is an entire "bulk" of air, in principle it could blow at ultrasonic speed. The speed at which a compression wave (the sound) propagate through a medium is not limiting the speed at which the medium can move through space. 
This is just in case you or your son or a reader are tempted to give to the speed of sound a special status, it has no extra ones.